# JPA Passing a list of Strings in to IN clause in a native query (using citext)

Tags: java, spring, nativequery

I am trying to pass a list of Strings in to IN clause in a native query using citext for a case insensitive search. Everytime I try to test this query out using postman I get the following error:
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : ingredientFilter

Below is the query I am trying to test:

```
@Query(value = "select personal_recipes.name, personal_recipes.type, personal_recipes.comments, " +
        "personal_recipes.instructions, personal_recipes.rating, ingredients.name, ingredients.quantity " +
        "from personal_recipes " +
        "inner join ingredients on personal_recipes.name = ingredients.recipe_name " +
        "where (ingredients.name::citext in (:ingredientFilter))" , nativeQuery = true)
List<PersonalRecipesEntity> getPersonalRecipesByIngredient(@Param(value = "ingredient") List<String> ingredientFilter);
```

I am confused as this query works when I test it out in Dbeaver.

I tried removing the brackets around :ingredientFilter. It did not change anything. I am new to Spring boot and havent been able to find anything online.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query(value = "select q.* from sde.pqrs q where q.fecha_radicado between :fechaInicial and :fechaFinal and q.radicado in (:radicados)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Pqrs> consultaRadicadoDeVisita(@Param("fechaInicial") java.sql.Timestamp fechaInicial,
            @Param("fechaFinal") java.sql.Timestamp fechaFinal,
            @Param(value = "radicados") List<String> radicados);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be exposed via the name declared using `@Param`. You should rename `ingredient` by `ingredientFilter`. You can find more about the subject [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-named-parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that. I now get the error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" This seems odd as the syntax should be fine as I tested it in Dbeaver.

Comment: Named parameters are not supported by JPA in native queries, only for JPQL. You need to remove the `nativeQuery = true`